# TSQL ParentID Recursive SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I have a table that is like this ...

```
ID     ParentID
1      0       
2      1
3      2
4      3
5      4
```

What I want to do is write a recursive TSQL statement that will get all of my parents ID. So for example, if I pass 5 into the stored procedure it would return 4,3,2,1.

Does anyone know how to do this? It would be very much appreciated if someone could help!

Comment: Not really an answer, but maybe a hint at a new direction.  If you are using SQL 2008, check out the HierarchyId datatype.  It's built for this.  It has support for retrieving all children, parents, siblings, etc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is an example how to achieve this using recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 5 

CREATE TABLE #tmp (id INT , ParentId INT)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(1,0)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(2,1)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(3,2);
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(4, 3);
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES(5,4);

    WITH parent AS
    (
        SELECT id, parentId  from #tmp WHERE id = @id
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t.id, t.parentId FROM parent
        INNER JOIN #tmp t ON t.id =  parent.parentid
    )

    SELECT id FROM  parent
    WHERE id <> @id;
```

--OR

```
    WITH parent AS
    (
        SELECT tmp1.id, tmp1.parentId  from #tmp AS tmp1
        INNER JOIN #tmp AS tmp2 ON tmp1.id = tmp2.parentId
       WHERE tmp2.id = @id
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t.id, t.parentId FROM parent
        INNER JOIN #tmp t ON t.id =  parent.parentid
    )

    SELECT id FROM  parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive common table expression :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx